# Capitalize the author's name in the references

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I used the code below for Harvard style references but want to capitalize the author's name in the references.

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalsize}

Comment: Anyone with an idea to modify the agsm style in order to get the capital letters of the authors in the references.